# Can't recognize touches after MobAD interstitial Exits - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, interstitial

I am using Sprite Kit to make a game. I have interstitial MobAds's pop up after a game over every once in awhile. I have a class that is used to display the ad shown here:

```
import GoogleMobileAds

class GoogleAd : NSObject, GADInterstitialDelegate {

var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

func initAd() {
    self.interstitial.delegate = self
    self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadAd()
}

func popUpTheAd(rootViewController:UIViewController) {
    if(self.interstitial.isReady)
    {
        self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(rootViewController)

    }
}

private func createAndLoadAd() -> GADInterstitial {
    var ad = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-5240674847633441/2553248417")

    var request = GADRequest()

    request.testDevices = ["3a3b4295c2011b1532642603c82ab3d8"]
    ad.loadRequest(request)

    return ad
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    //self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadAd()
}

}
```

I am calling the `initAd()` in my `didMoveToView()` method within my scene and then calling the `popUpTheAd()` method when I want to show the ad. I pass the root view controller from the scene so that the ad can be presented from there. It works fine at first. The ad shows and you can exit it out. But when you exit it out, the `interstitialDidDismissScreen()` method is never called and the buttons that are on the menu under the ad don't recognize touches. It is almost like the ad is still there, just invisible. I have also tried putting all this code just within my Scene class and running it all from there but it does the same thing. What am I doing wrong? Help would be appreciated. Haven't seen anyone having problems like this. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
class HomeView: UIViewController,GADBannerViewDelegate,GADInterstitialDelegate{

    var interstitial:GADInterstitial!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
         super.viewDidLoad()
         self.createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }

    func createAndLoadInterstitial()
    {
          interstitial=GADInterstitial()
          interstitial.adUnitID="ca-app-pub-8545631742499087/3093965659"
          interstitial.delegate=self
          self.interstitial.loadRequest(GADRequest())
    }

    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) 
    {
          self.createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }
}
```

//----call banner

```
if (interstitial.isReady)
{
    self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be done in a viewcontroller? because I was trying to do it in a singleton so I could call it from my scene

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the delegate code from didMoveToView into the create and Load ad function? I am using the same code as you and the only difference is the delegate code location. Not sure that would make a difference tho.

Comment: I kept it in the same location and it worked. I forget what exactly it was but there was some little detail that I had to change.